# YQL Weather Forecast

Tags: yql, weather

I currently have a piece of code that only displays the current weather in a given zipcode. Can someone help me with getting a 5 day forecast. Here is what I have so far.

```
                        var loc = zipcode;
                    var u = 'f';

                    var query = "SELECT item.condition FROM weather.forecast WHERE location='" + loc + "' AND u='" + u + "'";
                    var cacheBuster = Math.floor((new Date().getTime()) / 1200 / 1000);
                    var url = '<http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=>' + encodeURIComponent(query) + '&format=json&_nocache=' + cacheBuster;

                    window['wxCallback'] = function(data) {
                        var info = data.query.results.channel.item.condition;
                        $('#wxIcon').css({
                            backgroundPosition: '-' + (61 * info.code) + 'px 0'
                        }).attr({
                            title: info.text
                        });
                        $('#wxIcon2').append('<img src="<http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/we/52/>' + info.code + '.gif" width="34" height="34" title="' + info.text + '" />');
                        $('#wxTemp').html(info.temp + '&deg;' + (u.toUpperCase()));
                    };

                    $.ajax({
                        url: url,
                        dataType: 'jsonp',
                        cache: true,
                        jsonpCallback: 'wxCallback'
                    });
```

and here is the YQL console. [LINK](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=select%20%2a%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20location=%2727514%27)
I found forecast but I don't know how to implement it. I'm pretty new when it comes to YQL... Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have posted a complete sample here - https://gist.github.com/mvark/5231461

Check the [Yahoo Weather API](http://developer.yahoo.com/weather/) documentation for more details about the API